# Seamlessly forwarding a large number of emails in EML using Perl

Tags: perl, email

I have a large number of emails archived in my computer in EML format, which I have to forward to someone else. I handed them over a ZIP file with all the EML files, thinking that they would be easy to open: after all, all you need to do is to double-click on them, and Microsoft Outlook or Apple Mail will open them automatically...

...Except that now the other party says that they don't have Outlook, an asks me to forward them the emails to their Gmail account. So I have to write a Perl script to go through each of those EML files and forward it, as intact as possible (including attachments can be opened, original headers, etc.), to Gmail. This means that I can't simply add each EML as an attachment to a new mail and send it, since the other party won't be able to view the original message in that case.

After researching a bit, I find that there exists a series of "resent-from", "resent-to", etc. headers for this very purpose, but I don't know how to generate them using the Perl Mail modules that I'm familiar with. Basically: how can I forward a large number of emails stored as EMLs using Perl?

Comment: Tell them to google "how to open eml files"? I found this http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-open-eml-files-in-windows-7/8158751a-bc5a-4fd6-b8be-5755d2821c49 which seems to answer your question. I would rather find a sensible solution than write some Perl hack to fake it any day of the week and twice on sunday.

Comment: Nope. Your link says to open them using Windows Live Mail, but you'll notice that, as one commenter says below, Windows doesn't come with Live Mail by default either, so we're back to the situation of "they have to install something that they don't have". And using a text editor doesn't help, because they need to see the emails as they were originally formatted.

Comment: @PaulJ Actually, the accepted answer says "One can also rename them to mht and they will open in IE to show any HTML content." IE *does* come with Windows by default.

Comment: Sure, but in that case you can't see the From, To, Date... headers of the emails, only the content. They need to see the emails as... well, emails.

Comment: @PaulJ There may be arguments against such solutions, but my opinion remains: Using Perl for this should be considered a last desperate attempt. Can't you open the files with Outlook and convert them for him then? EML seems to be somewhat of a standard format that many programs should be able to read.

Comment: Well, there are several hundreds emails, so converting them all by hand... ugh. Besides: convert... to what format? Ideally, they should be able to see the emails with the original formatting: From/To/Date headers, signatures, attachments. I don't know of any other file format that can conserve and show all this information. I picked EML as a format to save those emails precisely because I thought that it was as standard as it gets; how could I know that there were businesses for whom Outlook is "too advanced"...

Comment: @PaulJ Well, what I want to know is how they could receive this file by email without having some way to read emails or email files. Which is why I am assuming your user lacks knowledge, and that what s/he is asking for is probably not what they really want.

Comment: Unfortunately, [gmail doesn't appear to support the .eml format](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31689/how-to-view-an-attached-email-in-gmail). You could create a gmail account for yourself, enable IMAP, and drag-and-drop the emails in Outlook to import them into gmail (details [here](http://www.zoliblog.com/2007/10/24/simplified-guide-to-importing-all-your-archive-email-into-gmail/)). You could then forward the emails to the other person's gmail account.

Comment: @TLP: they use Gmail for everything. This pile of EML emails were not originally sent or received by them, but they need to see them, and preferrably in their original format. After talking to them, it looked like the easiest solution was to forward them the emails to their Gmail account, where they could read them easily... and it would have been great, if I had had those emails "inside" my mail program (then I'd only have had to forward them). Instead, I have those emails in my filesystem as EML files; thus the problem.

Comment: @PaulJ I know that if you sent me "hundreds" of emails to my email account, I would probably be very upset indeed. What you could do is add some suitable tag to this question such as [tag:eml], [tag:outlook] to get some more informed people to advise you.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: thanks! I'm following your suggestion, and it's working so far (although I'm using Thunderbird and ImportExportTools for doing so). I've created a Gmail account only to host these mails, and will hand over the password to the interested party.

Answer (score 3):

From my understand .eml files are usually just the plain mail in rfc822 format. So maybe you just might use swaks (swiss army knife for SMTP, written in perl - http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) and pipe all mails with this tool to gmail.
Or you might try the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SMTP;

for my $eml_file ( glob('*.eml')) {
    open( my $fh,'<',$eml_file ) or die "cannot open $eml_file";
    warn "processing $eml_file....\n";
    my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new('your.mail.server', Debug => 1 )
        or die "connect failed: $!";
    $smtp->mail('your@email.here');
    $smtp->to('somebody@gmail.com');
    $smtp->data or die "server will not accept mail: ".$smtp->message;
    $smtp->datasend($_) for (<$fh>);
    $smtp->dataend or die "send mail failed: ".$smtp->message;

    # rename so it does not get processed twice
    rename($eml_file,"$eml_file.done");
}
```

This should take all *.eml files from the local dir and send them unchanged through your mail server, which then should forward them to gmail.com. If your server needs authorization have a look at the Net::SMTP 
manpage on how to do it. If it needs SSL too have a look at Net::SSLGlue::SMTP (search for it at CPAN).

Of course you should try it with a single mail first :)